# What is the correct syntax with nested for() loops in php and has differentiating increments?

Tags: php, for-loop, syntax, increment, nested-loops

I am trying to build a loop structure where I know that maximum # of loops and where there is a separate increment increase for certain fields/inputs.  With this in mind I am thinking that I should pursue a nested for() loop structure.

As an example, let's say that the echoed goal, might look something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="1" secondaryId="1" ></td>
        <td><input id="2" secondaryId="1" ></td>
        <td><input id="3" secondaryId="1" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="4" secondaryId="2" ></td>
        <td><input id="5" secondaryId="2" ></td>
        <td><input id="6" secondaryId="2" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="7" secondaryId="3" ></td>
        <td><input id="8" secondaryId="3" ></td>
        <td><input id="9" secondaryId="3" ></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc -->
</table>
```

So the id in this example increase by one at every input but the secondaryId increases by after every three inputs.  To help further visualize, consider the follow:

[image: example representation of the desired loop]

I tried some things along this line for code:

```
<?php
echo"<table>";
for ($t=1;$t<4;$t++){
    echo"<tr>";
        for($y=1;$y<4;$y++){
            echo"<td><input id='$y' secondaryId='$t'></td>";
        }
    echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
?>
```

Quite obviously it is not working and echo's back this instead:

[image: example representation of what is happening with current efforts in loops]

I see exactly why the problem is occurring, because at every iteration(right word?) of the parent loop, the `$y` variable is reset back to 1.

How can I manipulate the loop(s) so that `$y` increments throughout the loop(s)? Is there a foreach combination that I ought to have considered?

Also, let's say that the above "`id`" and "`secondaryId`" type attributes are fixed and cannot be changed.

I have considered the last resort of just manually creating the field of inputs manually with the help of excel, but this seems laborious and promisses problems of debugging considering the field of inputs that I want to build is *50 rows* (`<tr>`) by *23 columns* (`<td>`)

---

**> UPDATE:**

I accepted Fabio's answer as it did work without fail, I wish I could have also accepted Maiden B.'s answer as this led me to create a mathematical solution in a single loop.

The code I will end up using is:

```
$m = 0;
echo"<table>";
    for($y=1;$y<4;$y++){
        echo"<tr><td>
        <input id='".(1 + ($m*3))."' secondaryId='$y' >
        <input id='".(2 + ($m*3))."' secondaryId='$y' >
        <input id='".(3 + ($m*3))."' secondaryId='$y' >
        </td></tr>";
        $m++;
    }
echo"</table>";
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use other variables wich will count both your loop according with your needs

```
$m = 1;
$l = 1;
echo"<table>";
for ($t=1;$t<4;$t++){
    echo"<tr>";
        for($y=1;$y<4;$y++){
            echo"<td><input id='$m' secondaryId='$l'></td>";
            $m++; //we increment here for ipunt id
        }
            $l++; //we increment here for secondaryId
    echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```

This will output

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input id='1' secondaryId='1'></td>
    <td><input id='2' secondaryId='1'></td>
    <td><input id='3' secondaryId='1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id='4' secondaryId='2'></td>
    <td><input id='5' secondaryId='2'></td>
    <td><input id='6' secondaryId='2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id='7' secondaryId='3'></td>
    <td><input id='8' secondaryId='3'></td>
    <td><input id='9' secondaryId='3'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for this, this did in fact work flawlessly.  Also, using a mathematical solution inspired by the solution presented by Maiden B. below, I was also able to construct a single loop achieving the same. Thanks!(I updated my question to reflect what I came up with)

Answer (score 0):

For the "echoed goal" it might be enough to use only 1 for loop. Your "id" attribute would contain the iterating variable `$i` and your "secondaryId" attribute would contain `($i div 3) + 1`:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    printf('<td><input id="%d" secondaryId="%d" ></td>', $i, ($i/3)+1);
}
```

The catch is to only increment one variable ($i) and let another value increment only when $i crosses certain limits (in this case every 3 steps).

The entire code would look something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <?php
        for ($i=1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
            printf('<td><input id="%d" secondaryId="%d" ></td>', $i, ($i/3)+1);
            if ($i % 3 == 0) { // boundary reached
                echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

I hope you get the point.

Comment: @Maiden B. thanks for your insights and suggestions.  I must admit that I could not entirely follow your scripting or syntax, which is not surprising considering my lak of education, but using your idea of integrating a mathematical solution in a singe loop, I was able to achieve the desired results in one loop.  I have update my question to reflet what I came up with.  I wish I could acept two answers here.

Answer (score 0):

> You Should Try This :-

```
<?php
echo"<table>";
$ids = 1;
for ($t=1;$t<4;$t++)
{
    echo"<tr>";
    for($y=1;$y<4;$y++)
    {
        echo"<td><input id='$ids' secondaryId='$t'></td>";
        $ids++;
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to not reset the first input id. e.g.

```
echo"<table>";
$inputId = 1;
for ($t=1;$t<4;$t++){
    echo"<tr>";
    for($y=1;$y<4;$y++){
        echo"<td><input id='$inputId' secondaryId='$y'></td>";
        $inputId++;
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```